# Get image from gallery with UIPopover and show it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get image from gallery and than display it in UIImageView. My problem is in displaying this image. My code:

```
- (void)getMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {

     UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

     self.popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
     self.popController.delegate = self;
     [self.popController presentPopoverFromRect:[fromGalaryButton frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     [self.popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
     self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
     [self updateDisplay];
 }

 -(void)updateDisplay {
     self.imageView.image = self.image;
     self.imageView.hidden = NO;
     [self.imageView reloadInputViews];
}
```

My `self.imageView` is displaying normally. But there is no any image in. There is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just picking in image from the gallery then the line of code in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method should be:

```
self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

You could also just update the imageView from within the method as such:

```
self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

This is how I did this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;
  imagePickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];

}

- (IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender {

if(sender == choosePhotoButton) {
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   [imagePickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:choosePhotoButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
}

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        [imagePickerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        imageViewer.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    }
```

Comment: Are you able to select a picture from the UIImagePicker but then the image will not show up in your image view? Or are you unable to pick an image in the first place?

Comment: Yeap, I checked it `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]`.

Comment: Create an NSLog inside your imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediWithInfo method. This will give some insight as to if the method is being called correctly. Also just to make sure, did you add the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol?

Comment: Hmm.. `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]` = NULL very strange

Comment: Try UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage for the key. Also I don't know if this makes a difference but I would make initialize the UIImagePicker in the view did load and then just present the popover when I press the button to get an image.

Comment: Got an error `Named service 'com.apple.PersistentURLTranslator.Gatekeeper' not found. assetsd is down or misconfigured. Things will not work the way you expect them to.` 0_o

Comment: Strange... Can you update your question with the code you are using now? Also what is your setup? Which version of Xcode and OSX are you running? When do you get this error?

Comment: Now it's all ok. It was probably xCode error. Change key to `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` was right way. Thanks a lot!